# How do I access individual headers from a API request response?

Tags: robotframework

I'm currently creating a test suite for a new API, at the moment I've sent a POST request and it's responding as expected.  However, I'm now performing further validation such as checking the status code and also wish to check the Location Header.  Problem being, through trial and error I've been unable to access to location header value from the response.  Below is some cut down code:

```
${POST_REQUEST}    Replace String   ${CLAIM_AVAILABLE_BASE_URL}     PLAN_NAME   ${VALID_PLAN}
${file_data}=    Get Binary File    Data/Json/API/GETNaviNetClaimID/valid_aries_claim_local_only.json
${POST_RESPONSE}    Post Request   APIService    ${POST_REQUEST}    data=${file_data}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${POST_RESPONSE.status_code}    ${HTTP STATUSCODE OK}
```

I can access the header object using:

```
 ${POST_RESPONSE.headers}
```

But so far I've been unable to pull out just the location header value.  Can anyone offer any assistance?  I'm using the Requests Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems possible using the below, just replace location with the key you're looking for.

```
${location_header}=    Get From Dictionary    ${POST_RESPONSE.headers}    location
```

I don't like this solution though so welcome to anything better!